# I've sent Bitcoin to my BCH address on Coinbase. How can I recover it?

Tags: coinbase.com, cross-chain-recovery

I sent Bitcoin from Binance to my BCH address in my Coinbase wallet, how can I recover it?
I have the address and confirmation from Binance. 
I have contacted Coinbase, but they haven't answered yet.
Thank you!

Comment: Check the TXID on a blockchain explorer, does it have any confirmations yet?

Comment: it shows 203 confirmations.   what is that mean?

Comment: it is also shown in btc,com as received.  Although  I didn't do the transaction trough btc.com.

Comment: Alright, if its 203 confirmations it should have gone through (it means that the block that the transaction was a part of have been confirmed 203 times). But considering what @Murch commented, that's a factor you need to consider.

Comment: It hasn't gone trough.  I think the fact that it is different coints, I was transferring btc to a bch address.  Will it come trough coinbase?

Comment: @dragonskater45: I'm not sure where you're going with your line of inquiry. The address that OP sent to is probably not being monitored on the Bitcoin side and that's why the deposit has not been credited yet. OP is at the mercy of Coinbase to recover their coins.

Comment: So back to the question, will the bitcoin sent trough binance with an address from bitcoin cash from my wallet in coinbase transfer? its been over 24 hours since I did the transfer?

Comment: If the BTC you sent to Coinbase is confirmed, then Coinbase have access to those funds, assuming no one is using that specific BCH address as a BTC address . So only Coinbase can help you recover them. Ask them nicely, and you got a good chance.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try.  But it seems like they will be stilling the coint if they keep it.

Comment: If you sent BTC to a BCH address then it would just show up in your BTC wallet on Coinbase. They create the address for both of your wallets just in case you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase has shite customer service. But they're who you need to wait for. They'll either be able to access the bitcoins and send them back or credit your account, or they might give you the private key and let you do it. Not sure what their policy is. But you should use a different exchange anyway. Try ShapeShift, Bitstamp, or CryptoPay

Comment: Thank you!  I was using binance, I just wanted to sendit to binance because they are linked to my account.   Have you heard of anybody recovering the Bitcoin?

Comment: I haven't, but I'm not really in the know in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get your coins back? I'm having the same problem...

Coinbase service told me this: "*Unfortunately, digital currency transactions using most blockchains are irreversible, meaning once they are sent there is no way to reclaim funds.
If you sent digital currency from your Coinbase account to an email address by accident, your funds will be returned to you in 30 days if the funds remain unclaimed. If the email address has not already been claimed, you could do so to ensure the funds are returned to you.*"

Comment: Hey man they are sending the same stupid message to everyone, and playing stupid like they don't know what's happening.  There is a lot of people that made the same mistake and to answer to your question, no they haven't done anything.  They are holding almost 1 bitcoin so over $10k.  Not happy about it, and I'm not going to seat and wait.  I'lo bring it to the courts if I have to.  I feel like we all should get together and bring it to the court . I will keep trying and keep posting the results here .  I suggest you do the same!

Comment: Yea I'm thinking the same, as I'm reading on social media (Twitter, FB) a lot of people are dealing with the same problem. I even sent them a message on Twitter that this can't stay unsolved, no answer.. But I did get an email yesterday from Coinify "Your transaction trade order 1465614 has expired. If your card has been charged an automatic refund will instantly be issued to your bank account. Please be aware that it may take a few days more for the refund to show on your bank transaction list."

But I'm not sure this is about Coinbase or not because I've never had something with Coinify..

Comment: I just got off the phone with coinbase and they said they will open a ticket but wont be able to do anything.  I cant believe that they will just steal our funds and no one can do anything.  I will research of a lawyer that can help and keep everyone posted.

Comment: They will open a ticket? What does that even mean.. They have to be kidding, wtf

Comment: I know... it means nothing.  I spoke with a supervisor but there is nothing they can do or want to do to recover .  I will be tweeting in Brian Armstrong (coinbase CEO and founder) tweet wall because I think it's stupid that people are loosing thousands of dollars into their accounts. I suggest you do the same.  We have to get these guys to do something!!!

Comment: I already sent a few dm's to Coinbase Support on Twitter, no answer. A lot of other people tweeted with hashtags and @Coinbase and stuff, nobody ever seems to answer these tweets... It's just not fair and above that if we did this with another 'platform' like if we bought the btc's via bitcoin.com it wouldn't even be a problem to recover these coins... It's just Coinbase that has to give us our private keys.