# I sent an amount of Bitcoins to my Bitcoin Cash-wallet on Coinbase instead of my Bitcoin-wallet on Coinbase. What now?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cash, coinbase.com

A few days ago I bought **bitcoins** (on btcdirect.eu) and sent them accidentally to my **BCH**-wallet on **Coinbase** (!). I contacted both btcdirect and Coinbase, unfortunately I received the same answer twice: they can't do anything about it.

The exact answer of Coinbase was: "*Unfortunately, digital currency transactions using most blockchains are irreversible, meaning once they are sent there is no way to reclaim funds. If you sent digital currency from your Coinbase account to an email address by accident, your funds will be returned to you in 30 days if the funds remain unclaimed. If the email address has not already been claimed, you could do so to ensure the funds are returned to you.*"

Does someone know what I can do in this situation? It's a big amount of money for me and I really can't lose it...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you get Coinbase to come up off the private key for the address you sent the coins to? (The coins still exist, and are likely sitting at that address on the other network, but you need the private key to do anything with them.)

Comment: see also: [I've sent Bitcoin to my BCH address on Coinbase. How can I recover it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66337/35293)

Comment: also related: [Accidentally sent Bitcoin Cash to Bitcoin address held by a third party](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62456/accidentally-sent-bitcoin-cash-to-bitcoin-address-held-by-a-third-party)

Comment: I tried to find something on FAQ of Coinbase: If you have sent BCH to an external address that was used only for BTC, you will need to obtain the private keys for that address and import them into a BCH wallet in order to access the funds stored there. Coinbase does not support the importing of private keys.